# Play user selected audio using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to play user selected files from phone's storage and then play them? If so, how to achieve this using Cordova? 
I have included the media and files plugins in project.

Html:

```
    <input type="file" id="audio" accept=".mp3,audio/*">
        <button id="play">Click me!</button>
```

Javascript:

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
   console.log(Media);
   function playAudio(url) {
      // Play the audio file at url
      var my_media = new Media(url,
         // success callback
         function () {
            alert("playAudio():Audio Success");
         },
         // error callback
         function (err) {
            alert("playAudio():Audio Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
         }
         );
         // Play audio
         my_media.play();
      }
      $("#play").click(function(){ 
         alert($("#audio").val());
         //Actual file path 
         //files:///storage/emulated/0/PlatinumLevelCirculation.mp3;         
         playAudio($("#audio").val());
      });      
   }
```

Comment: just add a `base64` encoded `<audio>` element in order to play it in the `WebView`. `<input type="file" id="audio" accept=".mp3,audio/*">` is in every case completely wrong, because this is not for uploading audio files.

Comment: I added audio element, but how'll I trigger it, How will I assign location to audio element from user selection ? I used Input tag as I wanted to select file for playing audio.

Comment: you'd need a plugin, which converts from audio file to `base64` string, because one cannot access the SD card alike the assets directory. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: @MartinZeitler It is actually possible. We can use cordova-plugin-filepath to get the file path and then add it as a source to audio element to play.

Comment: this might stop working with Android Q... there it's all SAF, storage access framework. and even below that, a `FileProvider` might be the preferred method of accessing files (when reading it does not matter much, but when 2 threads write the same file, this will be a certain race condition).